# React Beautiful DND, swap items if their values are equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a quick question. I am using "React beautiful DND" and I need to swap items positions. Let me explain it to you:

We have two different lists that hold different items. If the user drags one item from list A to list B, then a check if the dragged item's value is equal to ANY of the items in list B must be done and if an equal value item is found, then both items must swap places => dragged item from A to B must go to list B and the item with the same value from list B must go to list A in the same position.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

I am attaching a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dubinsky-loczp?file=/src/App.js) to see what is achieved for now. I have reorder and move functionalities. But I need to swap items when necessary.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To swap them in their current places you can check the second array for existence by any comparison you like using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), then swap them. Example:

```
function swapIfEqual(arrayA, arrayB, itemIndex){
  const originalItem = arrayA[itemIndex];

  const sameValueIndex = arrayB.findIndex((i) => i.value === originalItem.value);
  if(sameValueIndex === -1) { 
    return;
  }

  const sameValueItem = arrayB[sameValueIndex];
  arrayA[itemIndex] = sameValueItem;
  arrayB[sameValueIndex] = originalItem;
}
```

This will compare items based on their `value` property. If they are the same, they will be swapped.
If the array contains multiple items with the same value, the first one found will be returned by `find` (and also by `findIndex`).

You then use it like so:

```
const arrayA = [{id: 1, value: 200},{id: 2, value: 101}];
const arrayB = [{id: 3, value: 102},{id: 4, value: 200}];

swapIfEqual(arrayA, arrayB, 0);
console.log(arrayA); // [{id: 4, value: 200},{id: 2, value: 101}];
console.log(arrayB); // [{id: 3, value: 102},{id: 1, value: 200}];
//  -> id 1 has moved from arrayA[0] to arrayB[1]
// and id 4 has moved from arrayB[1] to arrayA[0]
```